# Imgur API returns HTTP 500 response

Tags: python, imgur

I have been using the Imgur API for the better part of six months now for a project by passing image URLs to mirror to Imgur. Lately whenever someone tries to mirror an image it instead is returning an 500 response. This has been a problem since last Wednesday or so.

Python code handling the API:

```
response = requests.post('https://api.imgur.com/3/upload', data={'image':message.attachments[0].url}, headers={'Authorization': ('Client-ID ' + clientID)}) #uploads attachment URL to imgur
```

Client ID:

```
6b91ec71f6af441
```

Any help would be appreciated! :D

Comment: Maybe try adding `type: "URL"` to the request

Comment: Is there an error message? Have you tried this in Postman?

Answer (score 0):

Adding in `type: "url"` appears to have fixed it. Maybe some change at Imgur caused it to break? No clue, but it's working now. Thanks for the help.